# what entries need to do in .conf files for call forwarding

Tags: asterisk

I'm using Asterisk 10,centos 6. and I'V done changes in conf file as below for call forwarding

```
"extension.conf"
exten => 0010,1,Wait(0.05)
exten => 0010,2,Queue(0010)
exten => 0010,n,Dial(SIP/0011,15)
exten => 0010,n,Dial(SIP/0012,15)
exten => 0110,1,Dial(SIP/0110)
exten => 0210,1,Dial(SIP/0210)

"queues.conf"
;----------------------QUEUE TIMING OPTIONS------------------------------------
timeout = 15
retry = 5
;timeoutpriority = app|conf
timeoutpriority = conf

[0010]
member => SIP/0010
[0011]
member => SIP/0011
[0012]
member => SIP/0012
```

Please suggest wheather i'm right if not then please suggest some answer based on given  .conf files

Answer (score 0):

No your are completly wrong here.

I think better read some book about queue and dialplan

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-ACD.html

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+howto+dial+plan

Comment: Hi arheops, Thanks for the links above I'V gone through those,But still not getting idea,I'v done chnages in extension.conf as         exten => 0010,1,Wait(0.05)
           exten => 0010,2,Queue(0010,0.04)
           exten => 0010,n,Dial(SIP/0011,15)
           exten => 0010,n,Dial(SIP/0012,15)
           exten => 0110,1,Dial(SIP/0110)
           exten => 0210,1,Dial(SIP/0210)

Comment: as  above edited extension.conf, assumption was when entity 18 calls 10 then it will establish but when entity 20 calls 10 at same time then as 10 was busy with 18,then call will be forwarded to 11 and if 11 is busy then forward to 12. In Queue(0010,0.04),0.04 is retry time for calling entity 10 if it comes busy,Please help its urgent or give idea

Comment: Please read again. In dialplan you need only one command Queue and need setup queue to call your extensions as YOU need.